# Does Google send text messages about deleting your email?

Tags: google-account, security

I received a text saying, “Wait is over and security for obry****@gmail.com was replaced.”

The email address is my email.

Is this a scam?

Comment: That doesn't even remotely resemble something that Google would send. It wouldn't hurt to do a [Security Checkup](https://myaccount.google.com/smartlink/security-checkup?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2F).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that identically worded messages were received by Microsoft customers (reported on [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/osecurity-oother/security-info-replaced/17c2b716-8ab8-4c0b-babf-056df7d6283e) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/7d6l49/wait_is_over_and_security_info_for_thhotmailcom/)), I can only conclude that it's a scam.

Google and Microsoft are not going to use identical messages, let alone with such strange wording as this one.